# Addition Tutor Program doesnt work properly ***read description***

Tags: c#, if-statement, addition, equals

Below is the code for a program called "Addition Tutor". The program generates 2 random numbers and requests the user to answer the addition of both the random numbers. The problem is that every time I answer the question correctly, the messagebox returns the else action ("Incorrect"). What's the Problem with my program? Please keep the answers simple, my programing knowledge and terminology is very limited. Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
namespace Addition_Tutor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create a random object.
            Random rand = new Random();
            {
                //Declare an Integer
                int number1;

                //Generate a random integer and assign it to number1
                number1 = rand.Next(400) + 100;

                //Send random number to numberlabel1
                numberLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(number1);
            }
            {
                //Declare an Int Variable
                int number2;

                //Generate a random integer and assign it to number2
                number2 = rand.Next(400) + 100;

                //Send random number to numberlabel2
                numberLabel2.Text = Convert.ToString(number2);
            }
        }

        private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                //declare an Int Variable for Correct Answer
                int correctAnswer;
                correctAnswer = Convert.ToInt32("" + numberLabel1.Text + numberLabel2.Text);

            //check to see if the userAnswer and correctAnswer match.
            int userAnswer;
            userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(answerTextBox.Text);

            if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Answer is Correct");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Answer is Incorrect");
            }
        }
        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //clear the labels and textboxes.
            numberLabel1.Text = "";
            numberLabel2.Text = "";
            answerTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //close the form
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how far have you got with diagnosing the problem yourself? Have you run it in a debugger? I'm pretty sure you'll find the problem that way. (Hint: what do you expect `Convert.ToInt32(""+"10"+"5")` to return? It's not 15...)

Comment: (Note that time spent learning how to diagnose problems will pay for itself many times over. I suggest you make a commitment to yourself to work out how to do that - you'll save huge amounts of time in the long run.)

Comment: this is the 8th program I've created since taking the initiative to learn how to code. All issues I've come across with my code have been diagnosed through research on similar issues in this forum. The Convert.ToInt32(""+ "10" + "5") piece of code was used from another question.

Comment: Sure, you're a beginner - but that doesn't mean it's too early to learn to use a debugger or other diagnostic tools. If you'd stepped through the code in the debugger, you'd have seen that it was the calculation for `correctAnswer` that was causing the problem, and that everything else was irrelevant. You'd then hopefully have looked at what you were passing into `Convert.ToInt32` and realized that you don't add up 10 and 5 by parsing "105" as an integer.

Comment: Ill be sure to use it the next time I encounter a problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> correctAnswer = Convert.ToInt32("" + numberLabel1.Text + numberLabel2.Text);
> ```

You are "concatening" two numbers. Like `"1" + "2" = "12"`.

You need to parse them into `int` before adding them up:

```
correctAnswer = int.Parse(numberLabel1.Text) + int.Parse(numberLabel2.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help!